# handling clock_t overflow from std::clock()

Tags: c++, ctime

Question regarding clock tick count generated by `clock()` from `<ctime>`.  (Usage of `clock()` is covered in other [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3220477/how-to-use-clock-in-c))

On my system `clock_t` is an alias for `long` whose max value according to my compiler's `<climits>` is 2147483647.

```
clock_t delay = clock_t(10) * CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
clock_t start = clock();
while(clock() - start < delay); //Note Semi-colon here makes this null statement
std::cout << clock();
```

Running this I get roughly 10060. Which is consistent with `CLOCKS_PER_SEC` being `#define`d (for my system) as 1000.

So if there's 1000 `CLOCKS_PER_SEC` then 2147483647 / 1000 = 2147483.647 seconds, which works out to be roughly 24-25 days.

I'm not sure if it's actually defined behavior by C++, but I note that common behavior of exceeding the `long` limit is to wrap to the negative end.

For example,

```
long m = long(2147483647);
std::cout << ++m << std::endl;
```

Would output: -2147483648

So suppose the program had been running for a long time before initializing `start`, and `start` happened to be initialized to 2147483647 (max possible `long` value).

At this point, I'd assume we'd start wrapping on values returned by `clock()` so getting values such as -2147482649 as we are approaching 2147483647 again.
So now my original code would probably take a very long time to complete the loop, much longer than the delay intended.

Is the the actual behavior?  Should this style pause only be used for delays less than a certain amount?  Is there some other check that ought be made to make this "safe"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What happens when you overflow a signed integral type is implementation
defined, and could be a signal.  And yes, this means that `clock()` can
only be used for a fixed length of time after the start of your process,
and probably only then if the implementation ensures that the first call
will always return 0 (the case on all implementations I know of).

Comment: Formally, the behavior of an overflow of a signed integral type is *undefined* behavior, not implementation defined. The difference is that for the latter, the implementation is required to document what it does. For the former, anything goes.

Comment: @PeteBecker Ah, yes.  It's the conversion of a value that does not fit which is implementation defined (but at least in C, may be an implementation defined signal).  I don't know why I got the two mixed up.

Answer (score 2):

use:
GetTickCount64();
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724411(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: This answer is less than helpful if the code in question isn't running on Windows, which the question does not state.

Answer (score 0):

If `clock_t` is defined as a signed type, then yes, that is the expected behavior.

If you're concerned about wrap-around, you could always cast the `clock_t` value to an `unsigned long` (which means you're assuming that `clock_t` is no wider than a `long`), and store/compare that value instead.

Comment: If you really want to do this safely, C99 and C++11 have uintmax_t, which is a typedef for the largest unsigned type. A slightly less safe approach would be to use unsigned long long; the advantage of uintmax_t is that implementations are allowed to provide larger integral types, and there's a remote possibility that clock_t would use such a larger type. Personally, I'd use unsigned long, as originally suggested.

Comment: Hey, welcome to StackOverflow, @PeteBecker! Long time no see.

Comment: Thanks, @Loadmaster; been hanging around newsgroups too long.

Comment: What's worse is I found that `clock()` returns `-1` if elapsed time is unavailable.  Though, `-1` also could represent a "valid" time since `clock_t` is a signed type, and would not be visible in an unsigned cast?