# C++ noob: I need help creating a simple timer function

Tags: c++, visual-studio, countdowntimer

I'm a C++ beginner. I'm searching for a way to may a simple timer function for a very simple console game (class assignment). Hopefully a preexisting  function from a common library? Please keep it simple since I am new. Thanks. Sorry if I'm not wording this correctly. Brand new to this forum as well!

Comment: you can learn from this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3220477/how-to-use-clock-in-c

Comment: OT : SO is not a "forum".

Comment: @DanielKamilKozar and its upvoter: I preatty don't understand what is OT here. It is a simple question, but still a question, that admit answers. It if is too simple for you just don't aswer. Slamming up the door to a newcomer doesn't make we better.

Answer (score 1):

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/c/time

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/

It's not that different from any other loop or iteration, simply use the given values/constant as your condition.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the `time` function from `#include <time.h>`. Use it to get a start and stop time, then subtract to get the elapsed time. Info [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/time/).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using plain C++ in Win32 there is a function `SetTimer()` from the `Win32 API` that goes like this

```
UINT myTimer = SetTimer ( hwnd, ID_60SECONDS, 60 * 1000, NULL );
```

You will then need to add a `case` statement to your `WndProc` to handle the elapsed timer

```
case WM_TIMER:
switch (wParam)

{

    case ID_60SECONDS:

    // We processed it, so return 0

    return 0;

}

break;
```

Unfortunately, this involves dealing with Win32 which is no that easy but once you got the hang it is very obvious.

I took the code from [this](http://suite101.com/article/using-the-win32-timer-api-a23678) tutorial.