# Error: the global scope has no "clock"

Tags: c++, visual-studio, time, clock

I want use `clock` function in my program so I am referring to [how to use clock().](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3220477/how-to-use-clock-in-c)

My code :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <ctime>

int main() {
    std::clock_t start;
    //clock_t start;  
    double duration;

    start = std::clock();
    //start = clock(); //This Also not working

    /* Your algorithm here */

    duration = ( std::clock() - start ) / (double) CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    //duration = ( clock() - start ) / (double) CLOCKS_PER_SEC;

    std::cout<<"printf: "<< duration <<'\n';
}
```

But still I am having compilation errors

> error C2039: 'clock' : is not a member of '`global
>   namespace''   ....\ctime
>   error C2873: 'clock' : symbol cannot be used
>   in a using-declaration ....\ctime
>   error C3861: 'clock': identifier
>   not found   ....\main.cpp

So I have checked `ctime` header file by opening in visual studio in that also

```
using _CSTD asctime; using _CSTD clock; using _CSTD ctime;
```

for this line it's gives an error

> Error: the global scope has no "clock"

Please help me to solve these errors?

Comment: Which version of vs are you using?

Comment: Assuming these are the **first** error messages, you'll have to conclude that something very nasty happened to your `time.h` header file.  Or the .h files that it #includes.  You'll have to get your machine fixed, spin the repair/reinstall wheel of fortune.

Comment: give errors messages with info about place in the code where they happened (file and line)

Comment: Is all that code in `main()` required to demonstrate the problem?

Comment: Have you checked and rechecked that there is not an #include <time.h> in somewhere? Eh?

Comment: using VS-2013 and I have this small code only and i don't have time.h somewhere.

Comment: Path of ctime is ...C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\include

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have looked into my program include path. I have seen there are two location where `time.h` is present.

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\include
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\include
```

Replaced `time.h` file of path `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\include` which was referring my program by coping from another  location.